# Wait for hover animation to finish before executing other

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Hopefully this isn't a repeated question, I can't seem to find the answer.
Here is my problem:

I have a hover animation done in jQuery, what I would like is if the user hover another link, I want the first animation to do the callback and than animate again.

Here is an example of what I've got so far : http://sebastien-crapoulet.fr/test/

If you have the link 'A propos', you will get the full animation, now what I want is if you go from 'A propos' to 'Portfolio', for the A propos callback to finish, than to execute the other hover animation.

I have fiddled around with .stop() and .filter(':not(:animated)'), unsuccessfully.

Here is what I've got so far :

```
$('nav ul li a').hover(function(){
    link               = $(this)
    color              = $(this).data("color")
    position           = link.position();
    background         = $('.menuBackground')

    if (color=="blue"){
        background.css({
            'background-color':'#99b3c4',
            'width':(position.left)+(link.width())+20+'px',
            'top':position.top+'px'
        })
        background.stop().animate({
            left:'0%'
        },500)
    }
    if (color=="green"){
        background.css({
            'background-color':'#91b6a5',
            'width':(position.left)+(link.width())+20+'px',
            'top':position.top+'px'
        })
        background.stop().animate({
            left:'0%'
        },500)
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},function(){
    background.stop().animate({
        left:'-100%'
    },500)
    return false;
})
```

Thanks in advance for any help you could give !

Answer (score 0):

When you the user hovers over the first element animate the second element closing AND the first element opening and vise versa.